# add a reboot and shutdown button to top panel

Tags: shutdown, reboot, lxpanel

I have just upgraded my Rasp Pi4 from Buster to Bullseye. I had to create a fresh installation but had copies of my previous disk image.

I have managed to get most things re-installed but noticed I lost a reboot icon and a shutdown icon that I vaguely remember adding to the panel some years ago. I have always found these easier to use than the Logout option from the Raspberry menu. However, I cannot recall how I created these including how the command was carried out for each.

I will have taken the instructions from someone else online but cannot find them now. The idea was to have buttons as shown below that are always visible at the top.

[image]

[image]